# How to pass a object with list object from javascript to controller in .Net

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic-arrays

I am currently trying to send an object with a list, but I do not understand why sends the object but the list I receive zero.

Structure:

```
public class Provider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Articles> Articles { get; set; }
}

public class Articles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Javascript

```
var articles = [];

articles.push({ Id: 1, Name: "Article Name 1" });
articles.push({ Id: 2, Name: "Article Name 2" });

var provider = {
    Id: 1,
    Name : "Provider Name",
    Articles : articles
};
```

And i used this call ajax

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: "/Provider/Save",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ provider: provider}),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Provider provider)
{
    // Code here
    return View();    
}
```

Comment: What does the POST's request body look like and what does the controller look like?

Comment: i update now can see controller

Comment: Do you get other values? E.g. `"Provider Name"`?

Comment: yeah, the provider catch id and  name but the list object in size 0

Comment: Don't send a string that looks like JSON as your data, just send you data, which is *already* JSON, i.e. `data: { provider: provider }` or just `data: provider`, since it will bind automatically to the single param.